# XML file format in c# using XmlWriter having namespace and prefixes

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

Here is the required XML format that I am looking for:

```
<mf:package 
 xmlns="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1 sch_manifest.xsd"
 mf:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1">
```

What I am getting is:

```
<mf:package 
 xmlns="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1 sch_manifest.xsd" 
 xmlns:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1">
```

The code I am using is:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(parentPathPackage + packageID + "_man.xml", settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("mf", "package", "urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("", "xmlns", null, "urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, "urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1 sch_manifest.xsd");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: here the difference is: mf:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1" this is required.
and I am getting:
xmlns:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1"

Comment: Your desired XML is not well-formed.  Upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error, *`Errors in the XML document: 1: 250 The prefix "mf" for element "mf:package" is not bound.`* Specifically, you define an element `<mf:package ...` but never associate the `mf` prefix to a namespace.  `mf:mf=".."` is not the correct way to do that.  `xmlns:mf=".."` **is** the correct way, i.e. `XmlWriter` fixed it for you automatically.  (That is, unless your XML is a fragment of some larger document that does define the `mf` namespace.)

Comment: @dbc: Your comment could be an answer, IMHO.

Comment: ```<mf:package xmlns="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1 sch_manifest.xsd" mf:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1">
  <mf:metadata allOrNone="0" contentProviderID="KM_SEC_CONTENT" contentProviderIDScheme="Knowledge Mosaic ID" id="abc">
    <mf:dataFiles mf:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1">```

Comment: more of the content which is required ^^

Comment: yes @dbc. thanks! turns out, the required file was not in correct format. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are writing the [root XML element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), your desired XML is not well-formed:

```xml
<mf:package 
   xmlns="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1 sch_manifest.xsd" 
   mf:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1"> <!--mf:mf is not correct -->
```

Upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error,

> *Errors in the XML document: 1:   250 The prefix "mf" for element "mf:package" is not bound.*

Specifically, you define an element `<mf:package ...` but never associate the `mf` prefix to a namespace.  `mf:mf="..."` is not the correct way to do that.  Instead, a namespace declaration attribute [must either be **xmlns** or begin with **xmlns:**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#dt-NSDecl), so `xmlns:mf="..."` **is** the correct way:

```xml
<mf:package 
   xmlns="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1 sch_manifest.xsd" 
   xmlns:mf="urn:x-lexisnexis:content:manifest:global:1">  <!--Corrected -->
```

Since this is the XML you are actually getting, `XmlWriter` generated well-formed XML for you automatically.